# Get argument list from within __init__

Tags: python

How can I get argument list from within `__init__`? For example in the following, `save_hyperparameters` saves everything but the ignore parameter can stop it from happening. This is the [default](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/hyperparameters.html#excluding-hyperparameters) behaviour of the pytorch_lightning package. Basically I want to stop it from saving anything.

I think the `inspect` module has something to do with this, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```py
class LightningModule(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(
        self,
        model: models.BaseModel,
        tokenizer: data.Tokenizer,
        lr:float,
        weight_decay: float,
        loss_fn: LossType
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.lr = lr
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn
        self.save_hyperparameters(ignore=["model", ...])
```

Comment: So you want to add items to the `ignore` argument? Or do you just want to get it?

Comment: look at `inspect.getcallargs` and if that is not right `inspect.get*`.